# A sequence in which liminf < limsup

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limsup-and-liminf

In this question we are looking for a sequence in which liminf is strictly less than limsup. A majority of the examples that I came up with and found were in which liminf<=limsup. As for the second part of this we are also looking for subsequences that converge to liminf and limsup. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "A majority of the examples that I came up with and found were in which liminf<=limsup" An *overwhelming* majority, I would say.

Comment: Yea an "overwhelming" majority is true! @Did

Answer (score 4):

Take $a_n=(-1)^n$. You have $$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} (-1)^n = -1 < 1 = \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(-1)^n$$

Comment: Even simpler than mine :)

Comment: And now when n is odd our subsequence would converge to (-1) and when n is even our subsequence would converge to (1). Now that both of these converge to something completely different we can say our sequence An is divergent correct? @TimRaczkowski

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right.

Answer (score 2):

How about 
$$a_n=
\begin{cases}
1+\frac1n, & n\text{ even}\\
-1-\frac1n & n\text{ odd}.
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way to think of an example of a sequence whose $lim \ inf < lim \ sup$ is to choose a *bounded* but *not convergent* sequence.

If a sequence is not bounded, and let's say, diverges to (positive) infinity, then $lim \ sup = lim \ inf = +\infty.$

Similarly, recall that a sequence converges $\iff lim \ sup = lim \ inf = limit.$

So for a bounded but not convergent sequence, you can choose, say, $a_n := \{0 , 1, 0, 1, 0,  1, 0, 1, 0... \}. $ Then $lim \ inf = 0 < \ lim \ sup = 1.$ You do not necessarily have to pick a sequence that alternates between only two values, but such a sequence makes it easy to pick two subsequences that converge to $lim \ inf$ and $lim \ sup.$ Here, the subsequence ${a_n}_k$ for all $n$ odd converges to $0$, while the subsequence ${a_n}_l$ for all $n$ even converges to $1$.